# JS opacity - Why is this working on jsfiddle but not in live environment?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've found the code below on stackoverflow and would like to implement in on my page
This is working on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7RHxz/ but not when I preview the page in live environment on my web browser. I suspect that this might be due to the "on load" process or something like that?
I've just added the script below just before . Maybe there's something missing? Thanks

```
   <script> 
   var target = $('#intro-right');
var targetHeight = target.outerHeight();

$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
    if(scrollPercent >= 0){
        target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
    }
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code how you actually put all of this together on your site? Maybe even a link (along with the code).

Comment: In any case you could try wrapping it into jQuery's `ready` function. I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7RHxz/1/

Comment: "I've found the code below on stackoverflow and would like to implement in on my page" - this bodes ill. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for actually knowing what you're doing. If you're handwaving the "onload process" maybe you should first understand how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, sounds like you forgot to put in the `ready` function.

```
<script>
$(function () {
  // Put your code here...
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Greg I posted the exact same thing first, only as a comment, and didn't get so much as an answer. Oh well.

Comment: I noticed that - but unfortunately can't credit you for this if this was not a proper answer, or can I? Thanks anyway!